# Integrating middle tier between Java Desktop Application & MySQL Server

Tags: java, mysql, swing

My Current application working in network environment, each user run the application from their desktop to connect to the database server.
Since, the application dealing with many transaction that accrued from multiple station during working day, I would like to ensure there will be no confectionist within same record, since the data shared between all stations & each employee working on these records.

The application working as ERP solution there will be many kind of transaction for (Receipts, Payments, sales, purchases, etc).

For that I need to make sure there will be no transactions could be edited from two users at same time.

I searched the internet for solutions, what I understood:
- Applications deals with 3-tier will achieve this approach.
- Applications should run as client server using web server.

- My Client: Java Desktop Application SE Thin Client.
- My Server: MySQL Database server.
- I don't want to go web application.
- What i need to achieve this?
- What is could be used to get functionality as 3-tier.

Answer (score 0):

> Replace Apache with [Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/) which is an embeddable web server built with
>   java. Jetty can serve php pages if it's linked to the php executable.
>   MySQL is not a great option for this at all - if you need a portable
>   high powered solution use MongoDB which you can simply package and run
>   alongside your application.

Comment: MySQL Server is Central Server which all users connect to it within the network. 25 - 50 users will share the same database records & transactions.